# Returning an object of any type

Tags: java, oop, generics

In my **cache class**, I'm going to have a function which writes the serialized version of an object (undecided type) to a file, something like this (generic function):

```
public <O> void write(O object) {

   // ...
   serialize(file, object);
   // ...

}
```

Which works great, however, I'm unable to find a way to create a **method which can return any object**, like the `write()` method can take any object. Looking for something like this:

```
public <O> read() {

   // ...
   O object = unserialize(file);
   // ...

   return object;

}
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you having compilation issues? Or are you asking how can you create a generic instance at run-time?

Comment: p.s. your `write` could just be written as `public void write(Object object)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specify the return type of type Object:

```
public Object function(...)
```

That way the return type will always be of type Object (since all objects are descendants of `Object`), so they will be accepted.

Comment: Awesome dude! Answers should be like this simple, anyhow I'm a newbie to java world.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean

```
public <O> O read() {
```

this is almost useless because it is much the same as

```
public Object read() {
```

Comment: `public <O> O read()` is slightly different from `public Object read()`: it casts the return type implicitly depending on the context surrounding the call.

Comment: @Jeffrey It can in theory, but often it doesn't and you have to specify the type anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly... You could wrap both methods inside a class and parametrize the class with the object's type, like this:

```
public class ReaderWriter <T> {
    public ReaderWriter(File file) {...}
    public void write(T object) {...}
    public T read() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do that by making the whole class generic

```
class Cache <O extends Serializable> {

    public void write(O object) {
        serialize(file, object);
    }

    public O read() {
        O object = (O)unserialize(file);

        return object;
    }
}
```

Note the cast of the returned object.

Besides that you should use `<O extends Serializable>` instead of just `<O>`. This assures that your type parameter id a type that is serializable. This is needed if you want to save (serialize) objects and prevents later errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the caller to read() knows which type it expects to get. This is a reasonable assumption because he is going to assign the return value to some variable:

```
MyType o = read(...); // Caller knows he's going to get a MyType object
```

If this assumption is true, then you should change the `read()` method such that it takes a class object:

```
public<T> T read(Class<T> t) {
   ... 
}
```

Then the call site will look as follows:

```
MyType o = read(MyType.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
public <O> O read()
```

is valid and will do what you want (return any type the caller wants). Whether this is a good idea is another matter